# Replace reducer proper typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I create a replace reducer based on the [docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting#reducer-injection-approaches) but I'm using typescript and redux docs don't have any example of how to type replace reducer properly, I make a try but my try overrides the `useStore` ignoring the generics losing the typing of `getState()`.

Component:

```
interface State {
  sim: number;
  nao: string;
}

function Experimente() {
  const store: InjectableStore = useStore<State>();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  store.getState(); // any
}
```

redux config:

```
export const initStore = () => {
  const store: StoreCreator & WithAsync = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(thunk),
    ),
  );

  store.asyncReducers = {};

  store.injectPageReducer = (pageReducer) => {
    store.asyncReducers['page'] = pageReducer;
    store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.asyncReducers));
  }

  return store;
}

function createReducer(asyncReducers?) {
  return combineReducers({
    ...staticReducers,
    ...asyncReducers
  })
}
```

type definition:

```
export interface WithAsync {
  injectPageReducer?: (asyncReducer: Reducer) => void;
  asyncReducers?: IGenericObject<any>;
  replaceReducer?: typeof combineReducers;
}

export type InjectableStore = ReturnType<typeof useStore> & {
  injectPageReducer?: WithAsync['injectPageReducer']
}
```

How can I type the `replaceReducer` strategy keeping the `useStore` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your type `InjectableStore` is not receiving any information about your store.  The type `ReturnType<typeof useStore>` will not apply your specific state type because `useStore` is generic, but you have not provided it with the generic arguments, so it uses its own defaults instead. The signature of `useState` is:

```
export function useStore<S = RootStateOrAny, A extends Action = AnyAction>(): Store<S, A>;
```

So `ReturnType<typeof useStore>` becomes `Store<RootStateOrAny, AnyAction>`.

`Store`, `useStore`, `Reducer`, etc. are all generics which are dependent on two values: `S` which is the shape of the state and `A` which is the type of allowed actions.  `A` can be optional and default to allowing any standard `Action`.  But if `S` is not provided then these types don't know anything about your state.

Basically any time you use a type which was imported from "redux" or "react-redux" you will need to provide it with the `S` argument.  You can make your custom types like `InjectableStore` be generics which take a store shape and pass it down, or you can have them always set the store to your interface `Store`.  The second approach is easier so let's do that.

You cannot use `ReturnType<typeof useStore<S, A>>` because that's an invalid syntax, but it's fine because we saw in the function signature above that the return type is `Store<S, A>` which in your case is `Store<State>`

The need to apply types goes deeper because the property `{injectPageReducer: (asyncReducer: Reducer) => void;}` should know that the reducer is not just `Reducer<any>` (which is implied), but is specific to your state (or part of your state, in this case).

The part where this gets to be tricky is that it seems like when you call the `injectPageReducer` function which in turn calls `store.replaceReducer`, you are changing the shape of your state from an object with keys `sim` and `nao` to an object with keys `sim`, `nao`, and `page`.  This is bad and we don't want to do this.  The signature of the `replaceReducer` function actually tells us that the replacement reducer needs to operate on the same state shape `S` as the original one:

```
export interface Store<S = any, A extends Action = AnyAction> {
  /** ... */
  replaceReducer(nextReducer: Reducer<S, A>): void
  /** ... */
}
```

A quick fix is to make `page` an optional property on `State` but this causes errors down the line. It's better to make it required and set a default value.

I actually don't love this setup with having `asyncReducers` set as a property of `Store` rather than a temporary variable passed to `replaceReducer` but I see that it comes directly from the [redux docs example](https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting#defining-an-injectreducer-function) so I'll roll with it.

[Here is your revised code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-kare-ew1lr?file=/src/index.ts)

I got rid of `WithAsync` and made it into one `InjectableStore` interface which has all the properties of a `Store` plus (maybe) your two add-ons.  Since the add-ons are optional, you'll need to check that `injectPageReducer` exists before calling it.

```
export type InjectableStore = Store<State, MyAction> & {
  injectPageReducer?: (pageReducer: Reducer<PageState, MyAction>) => void;
  asyncReducers?: Partial<ReducersMapObject<State, MyAction>>;
};
```